# storage handling of docker layers

Tags: docker-registry, gitlab-ci

When I push a new docker image to a registry with tag "A", all layers wi be uploaded and saved on the server. The same procedure happens, when I push another image with tag "B".

But when I push a new image with tag "A", all following pulls will get this new image.

What does the docker registry do with these "old unused layers"?
It is really important if you talk about spaces. Let's say you have an image with 2GB which is generated by a ci job but only uses the same tag (like an update). If docker registry does not delete old layers, the repository will grow very fast.

I am using GitLab Registry which is using a docker registry.